# CanopyTax File download with Pupeeteer is not working

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to automate the download of a CSV file from the Canopy Tax website. The page has a dropdown menu with an "Export CSV" option. Despite my efforts, the download isn't working as expected. I've provided the relevant HTML structure and my Puppeteer code below.
Here is the page.
[Payment Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6fSy.png)

And this is the html content:

```
<div class="cps-dropdown">
    <div class="cps-btn-icon">
        <a class="cps-link cp-m-0">
            <span class="cps-icon cps-icon-more"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="cps-dropdown-menu cps-pull-right" role="menu" style="z-index: 50;">
        <li>
            <a>
                <svg canopy-styleguide="k1" class="cp-icon af-line-square-up cps-icon cps-dropdown-menu__icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <use href="#af-line-square-up" xlink:href="#af-line-square-up"></use>
                </svg>
                Export CSV
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
scrapeCanopyPayments = async () => {
    try {
        const C = {
            username: 'useremail',
            password: 'password',
        };
        const USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#canopy-login-ui-email';
        const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#canopy-login-ui-password';
        const CTA_SELECTOR = '#canopy-login-ui-login';
        const OTP_NEXT_SELECTOR = '.cp-button--primary';
        const OTP_INPUT_SELECTOR = '.cp-input';
        const DOWNLOAD_CSV_SELECTOR = 'ul.cps-dropdown-menu.cps-pull-right li a';

        const websiteUrl = 'https://app.canopytax.com/#/login';
        const paymentUrl = 'https://app.canopytax.com/#/billing/payments/collected';
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            dumpio: true,
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
        await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
        await page.goto(websiteUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'login.png' });

        // Log in
        await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(C.username);
        await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(C.password);
        await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);

        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'login2.png' });

        // Handle OTP
        await page.click(OTP_NEXT_SELECTOR);
        await page.waitForNetworkIdle();
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'otp-input.png' });
        await sleep(50000);
        const otp = await this.getOtpFromEmail();
        await page.click(OTP_INPUT_SELECTOR);
        await page.keyboard.type(otp);
        await page.click(OTP_NEXT_SELECTOR);
        await sleep(4000);
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'dashboard.png' });

        // Navigate to payment page
        await Promise.all([
            page.goto(paymentUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 }),
            page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }), // trigger a navigation
        ]);

        await sleep(4000);

        // Trigger CSV download
        await page.click(DOWNLOAD_CSV_SELECTOR);
        await page.waitForNetworkIdle();

        await browser.close();
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
};
```

Despite executing the click on the "Export CSV" option, the file download isn't happening. I've checked the console and network requests but haven't found a solution. Any insights or suggestions on how to make the download work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have [race conditions](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation) in your `waitForNetworkIdle()` and `waitForNavigation()` calls, including those [near clicks](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation#not-using-promiseall-when-triggering-navigation-with-a-click). It's good that you've shown all the code, but without the un/pw, there's no way to easily help.